# How to install the Restful client of codeigniter?

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter

I am trying to install the Restful client of CodeIgniter: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restclient.
For the moment I just copy the Rest.php file in the libraries directory. But when I load the library via:

```
$this->load->library('rest', array(
            'server' => 'http://localhost/restserver/index.php/api/api',
            'http_user' => 'admin',
            'http_pass' => '1234',
            'http_auth' => 'basic' // or 'digest'
        ));
```

It rediects me to the GitHub website. How can I install it correctly?

Comment: Do you meet all the requirements to use the client? https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restclient/blob/master/README.md#requirements

Comment: The sparks url is cannot open.